# Console guess game

Tags: c++, game, number-guessing-game

This is the console program that I've written in C++. It's a game where you have to guess a randomly picked number within the range 0-200. I just took a look at syntax and how to get started with C++ and VS and I was able to write this game almost immediately, but tweaking and improving it took me some time. I have a lot of experience with PAWN.

Anyway, does my code look alright? Please let me know if there are any bad practices that you notice or anything wrong.

```c
#include <iostream> // cin(), cout(), printf()
#include <time.h> // time()
#include <windows.h> // Sleep()

/* Variables */
int number;
int tries;
int max_tries;


/* Functions */
void game_init(int try_count);
void game_process();
void game_decide();
int game_check(char input);

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

    game_init(8);
    game_process();
}

void game_init(int try_count)
{
    number    = rand() % 200;
    tries     = 1;
    max_tries = try_count;
    printf("You have %d tries to guess a random number we've picked for you. (withing a range 0-200)\n", max_tries);
}
void game_process()
{
    do
    {
        printf("\nTry %d/%d: ", tries, max_tries);

        int input;
        scanf_s("%d", &input);

        if (game_check(input) == 1)
        {
            std::cin.get();
            break;
        }

        if (tries == 9)
        {
            printf("\n\n\nUnfortunately, you weren't able to guess the number.\nIt was %d!", number);
            printf("\n\nI wish you more luck the next time. Wanna try again? Type \"yes\" or \"no\".");
            printf("\nDo you want to try again? ");

            game_decide();
        }
    }
    while (tries <= max_tries);
}
int game_check(char input)
{
    if (input == number)
    {
        printf("\nCongratulations! You've guessed the number, it was %d!", number);
        printf("\n\nDo you want to play again? ");
        game_decide();

        return 1;
    }
    else if (input < number)
    {
        printf("\nThe number %d you've entered is lower than the number we're looking for.", input);

        tries ++;
        std::cin.ignore();
    }
    else if (input > number)
    {
        printf("\nThe number %d you've entered is higher than the number we're looking for.", input);

        tries ++;
        std::cin.ignore();
    }

    return 0;
}


void game_decide()
{
    char decision[3];
    std::cin >> decision;

    if (!strcmp(decision, "yes"))
    {
        std::cout << "\n\n\n";

        game_init(8);
        game_process();
    }
    else if (!strcmp(decision, "no")) 
    {
        printf("Quitting...");

        // Close the console after 1 second
        Sleep(1000);
        exit(0);
    }
    else 
    {
        printf("\n\nI'm not sure I understand what are you saying... Can you repeat that again, just \"yes\" or \"no\", please?");
        printf("\nDo you want to try again? ");

        game_decide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

- There's no need for `printf()` and `scanf()` in C++.  Instead, use:

  - `std::cout << "Some text..." << aVariable;` for outputting, or
  - `std::cin >> aVariable;` for inputting
- In C++, use `<ctime>` instead of `<time.h>`.  The latter is a C library.
- *Never* use global variables, unless they're constants.  Instead, pass `number` and `tries` to their relevant functions.
- If `max_tries` is supposed to be a constant, initialize it below the `#include`s as such:

  ```
  const int max_tries = 8;
  ```
- Since you're using `std::rand()`, which returns non-negative numbers, you could change `number`'s type to `unsigned int`.
- You should move `game_init()`'s contents to `main()` instead for clarity and easier program termination (via `return X`).
- `game_check()` should return a `bool` since it's conditional.  For `bool`s, 0 corresponds to `false` and 1 corresponds to `true`.

  It shouldn't need to display anything since that's not its purpose.  Instead, move those outputs to `game_process()`, remove the `std::cin.ignore()`s, and return the appropriate `bool`s.

  Remove the `return 0`; it should now return a value of `true` or `false` instead.

  The parameter for its prototype and definition should be an `int`, which you're already passing into it from `game_process()`.
- In `game_decide()`: instead of using a `char` array to hold `decision`, just make it a single `char` variable.  A "y" or "Y" could mean yes, and an "n" or "N" could mean no.  Then, your conditional statements could look like this:

  ```
  if (decision == 'y' || decision == 'Y')
  // do something
  else if (decision == 'n' || decision == 'N')
  // do something else
  else
  // try again
  ```

  You're doing a recursive call, which is absolutely unnecessary for this situation.  Instead, use a `while` or `do-while` loop to handle this.

  It should return a `bool` instead (for the same reason as `game_check()`).

  Clear everything from the "yes" and "no" blocks and instead have them respectively return `true` and `false`.  Then, back at `game_process()`, allow the loop to end if `game_decide()` returns `false` (meaning that the user no longer wants to play).  Thus, the program will fall back to `main()` and terminate nicely.  You would then no longer need `#include <windows.h>`.

Answer (score 5):

Jamal has many good points. Listen to them. In addition:

I'd argue that this is barely C++. Your code is written as if it was C, only with some C++ function calls instead.

**1: Take advantage of C++.** Your `game_` functions should probably be member functions in a `Game` class. You can make more use of the C++ standard library. In short, strive towards writing C++.

**2: Use `std::string` instead of `char[]`.** C++ strings are dynamic and can grow, they take care of memory management for you and generally make your life much easier. They can also be turned into a C-style string (i.e. a `char[]`) by calling `mystring.c_str()`.

3: In C++, we use `0` instead of `NULL`. In C++11, use `nullptr` instead.

**4: Avoid literal constants.** Consider for example your `if (tries == 9)`. Why exactly is this 9? Is that the maximum number of tries? Does it hold some magic meaning? If you declare `const int MAX_TRIES = 9;` somewhere, `if (tries == MAX_TRIES)` will become much easier to read. As an added bonus, you only have to change the code one place to change the maximum number of tries. I'm also wondering: Why are you checking `tries`against `9`, and not against your `max_tries` variable?

**5:** Regarding constants and Jamal's answer: C++ doesn't have a set coding convention. You don't *have* to write constants in `UPPERCASE_UNIX_CASE`. However, it's a common convention and I think it's a good one. I still think you should restrict the constant's scope as much as possible. It is okay to have a global or semi-global constant, but there's no reason to do so just because you can. If a constant is only used in a function or other restricted scope, then restrict the constant to that scope.

**6:** Using a `while` loop is generally more readable than a `do...while` loop. Unless you really need to force a first iteration (which you don't in this case), prefer `while` loops.

**7:** Use a loop inside `game_decide` instead of having it call itself. Recursion is in many cases wonderful, but this is not the place nor use for it.

**8:** On a game design level, consider telling the user if a guess is too high or too low, and remember the upper and lower bounds for him/her.

Comment: I don't agree with `ALL_UPPERCASE` being a common convention in C++ for constants. Rather, usage is conventionally reserved exclusively for macros.

Comment: Avoid all uppercase identifiers unless they are macros. The convention is `MACRO NAMES` are all uppercase. This is because macros have no scope thus your identifiers can potentially be trampled. So to avoid clashes with normal identifiers and those used by the pre-processor the convention is used. What you are seeing is that macros often define constants (in C). With C++ constants are more normally `type const` and thus don't have all uppercase names.

Comment: I disagree with using `0` as NULL pointer value. It makes no difference to the compiler (they are the same value). So the only reason to use one over the other is to help poor humans. The use of a name gives valuable context that makes the code easier to read (you know it is a pointer rather than an integer). But nullptr is the correct solution.

Comment: Can't agree that `do..while()` is any more/less common than `while` or even `for` (well for is probably the most prevalent (but just in my experience others may have totally different experience)). The point: Any is fine. Use the one that makes the most sense in the given context and makes the code easy to understand.

Comment: @Yuushi, @LokiAstari: I may very well be affected by the code bases I usually work in, and biased to believe that `UNIX_CASE` is common for constants. I'll keep in mind that both of you object.

Comment: @LokiAstari: I'm saying that `while` is more readable than `do..while()`, not that it is more common. I suspect it is more common as well, but that's beside the point. I think reading the condition first works better with how people parse code in their heads. I have even been criticized myself by using it in cases where it makes absolute sense. Therefore I stand by my comment: Unless `do..while()` makes sense, prefer `while`.

Answer (score 5):

The other two have made all the points I would have made.

I would strongly follow the advice of `@Lstor` to make the a `Game` class.

The only addition I have is about reading user input.
When dealing with user input (manual were errors can happen) it is best to deal with line input (users are used to typing something followed by a return). So write your code on the same model. When user input is expected read a line and validate. If its not what you expect print an error and try again.

The issue with `operator>>` for interactive user input is that it often leaves `\n` character on the input (or when you least expect it skips passed the `\n` (or multiple `\n`) looking for more user input)`.

```
 std::string  line;
 do 
 {
     std::cout << "Do you want to continue 'Y/N'\n";
     std::getline(std::cin, line);                        // Get users input.
     std::transform(line.begin(), line.end(), ::toupper); // uppercase answer
 }
 while (line != "Y" || line != "N");
```